# How to Get an Objects X position in processing

Tags: java, arrays, get, processing

I am trying to make Space Invaders in Processing. I am currently working on getting the enemy to move correctly. I have got them to be drawn in the right spot but I haven't gotten them to be moved correctly. Here is my code:

```
PImage mainPlayer;
PImage enemyPlayer;

float Xspeed = 60;
float Yspeed = 60;
float X;
float Y;

Enemy EnemyPlayer = new Enemy("EnemyPlayerSpaceInvaders.png", 10, 10, 6);

void setup() {
 size(1400, 800);

 //enemyPlayer = loadImage("EnemyPlayerSpaceInvaders.png");
 mainPlayer = loadImage("MainPlayerSpaceInvaders.png");


}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  Enemy[] enemyPlayer = new Enemy[60];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 1) {
      enemyPlayer[j *i] = new Enemy("EnemyPlayerSpaceInvaders.png", 50 + j * 100, 5 + 75 * i, 6);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 1) {
      if(enemyPlayer[j * i].alive){
        enemyPlayer[j * i].Draw();
      }
      enemyPlayer[j *i].moveAndDraw(6);
    }
  }
}


class Enemy {
  boolean alive = true;
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  String playerTexFile;
  PImage playerTex;
    Enemy(String PlayerTexFile, float X, float Y, float Speed){
     x = X;
     y = Y;
     speed = Speed;
     playerTexFile = PlayerTexFile;
    }

    void Draw(){
      playerTex = loadImage(playerTexFile);
     image(playerTex, x, y); 
    }

    void moveAndDraw(float Speed){
     playerTex = loadImage(playerTexFile);
     if(alive){
       x += Speed;
       if (x >= 1300) {
          x = 100;
          y += 50;
        } 
     } 
   }
}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

The Draw function works but what you're seeing that is messing it up is the `moveAndDraw()` function.

And the enemy drawings aren't moving. I have made this before with c++ SFML but in that there is a very basic getPosition function. The reason I want to get position is that right now I'm having to use inaccurate numbers as the X and Y position and for the enemy to move correctly I need to know exactly what it's position is. I have checked multiple pages on processing.org but none of them helped. I haven't found any getPosition void and all the ones I've seen other people using a void to do this I just haven't been able to get it to work. If there is some code that could get me this to work or just some function I've looked over and even a website page I could look at I'd be open to it. Please tell me anything I can do to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you recreate the enemies in every frame at it's initial position:

> ```java
> void draw() {
>    background(0);
>
>    Enemy[] enemyPlayer = new Enemy[60];
>    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
>        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j += 1) {
>            enemyPlayer[j *i] = new Enemy("EnemyPlayerSpaceInvaders.png", 50 + j * 100, 5 + 75 * i, 6);
>        }
>    }
>
>    // [...]
> }
> ```

You've to:

- Create a global array of enemies `Enemy[] enemyPlayer` (and delete `PImage enemyPlayer`).
- Create and initialize the enemies in `setup`.
- Use and move the existing enemies in  `draw`:

Further note, that your loops doesn't do what you expect it to do. Create the enemies in 2 nested loops. If `i` runs from o to 6 and `j` from 0 to 10, the the index of an enemy is `i*10 + j`.
The enemies can be moved in a single loop from 0 to `enemyPlayer.length`.

```java
//PImage enemyPlayer; <--- DELETE

// global array of enemies
Enemy[] enemyPlayer = new Enemy[60];

// [...]

void setup() {
    size(1400, 800);

    mainPlayer = loadImage("MainPlayerSpaceInvaders.png");

    // create enemies
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
            enemyPlayer[i*10 + j] = new Enemy("rocket64.png", 50 + j * 100, 5 + 75 * i, 6);
        }
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(0);

    // move enemies
    for(int i = 0; i < enemyPlayer.length; ++i ) { 
        if(enemyPlayer[i].alive){
            enemyPlayer[i].Draw();
        }
        enemyPlayer[i].moveAndDraw(6);
    }
}
```

Comment: So they are now moving an along the X axis then going down but it is very random so go the right speed some just go super fast. None of them reset correctly. I think the problem is in moveAndDraw() we are still not adding to accurate numbers, and in draw we need to plug in the 2 parameters(X, Y). I don't know what I should plug in.

Comment: What should I plug in as the parameters though when calling the Draw() function.

Comment: In the EnemyClass the draw function needs to know the position of the enemyPlayer it is drawing so what should I tell it the position is. This is why I was wondering how to get the position of an object.

Comment: @ThatGuy What!? `Draw()` has not any parameter at all. `Draw()` uses the attributes `x` respectively `y`. The class members `x` and `y` are set on the constructor of `Enemy` and are updated `moveAndDraw`, so `Draw` doesn't need a parameter, because the object knows its position itself.

Comment: Oh sorry I was messing with it and set Draw() as needing parameters that is my fault. Your answer is correct.